# How to change the font in matplotlib using an absolute path?

Tags: fonts, matplotlib

Using `matplotlib.rc` I can change the font family and which fonts are in each family.

```
rc('font',family='serif')
rc('font',serif='Helvetica')
```

However, I have a specific TTF font file that is not installed in the system and I would like to use it. Is there any way to specify an absolute path to the font configuration?

Answer (score 2):

There is a way to use a font which is not installed into the system. For example:

```
import matplotlib.font_manager
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.text

# load the font properties
font = matplotlib.font_manager.FontProperties(fname="/tmp/Warenhaus-Standard.ttf")
font.set_size(28)

# draw a figure
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.set_xlim(0,1)
ax.set_ylim(0,1)
ax.add_artist(matplotlib.text.Text(0.05, 0.45, "Special Font (Warenhauser)", fontproperties=font))
```

Creates:

[image]

If you look at the code and like the PyLab-style of using the stateful interface, the important part of the code is still the same (`font=...` and the kwarg `fontproperties=font`).

There are a couple of caveats, though. Maybe the most important is that the special font is not necessarily displayed on-screen if it is not installed (if the backend uses the OS fonts, as at least the MacOSX backend does), but it is still saved by `savefig`.

It might be quite instructive to have a look at `matplotlib.font_manager` documentation. The font management is actually quite sophisticated.

Comment: Is there anyway to change the global font setting so everything is drawn with the specified font?

Comment: I'd like to know how to do this settings on matplotlibrc. Anybody has the clue?!

Comment: thank god for this answer. i tried 10 different ways using the `addfont()` method and none of them work. the font manager for matplotlib is absolute garbage.